# MSBuild ExtensionPack not found

Tags: msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

I have installed the MSBuild.ExtensionPack (From CodePlex) on our BuildServer, but when a build triggered by a Build definition I get the message: "error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" was not found"
I am completely sure that this path is right!

I can run the very same .proj inside in a command-prompt at the server with no problem, it's only when I try to trigger it as a build definition it fails.

(The .proj-file is located at the server, at D-drive if that's should matter.)

Comment: Try /v:diag in the tfsbuild.rsp file as described in this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/05/03/tfsbuild-rsp-and-logging-verbosity-in-orcas.aspx

Comment: What identity (account) is running the Service?  Maybe that identity cannot see that path.